# Add page title in breadcrumb separately

Tags: prestashop, breadcrumbs, prestashop-1.6

Is there any possible way to have the page title in the breadcrumb tpl design.

On every page (product, category, cms, order, cart, etc) i want to have the page title in the breadcrumb area, just like the following example has: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnlpf.jpg

Can be this achieved without changing Prestashop's core files?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this. Edit `breadcrumb.tpl` file from your theme folder and add this code:

```
    {if $controllerName=="category"}
        {$category->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
    {elseif $controllerName=="product"}
        {$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
    {elseif $controllerName=="cms"}
        {$cms->meta_title}
    {else}
        {$smarty.capture.path}
    {/if}
```